# android asynctask handler how to create it correctly plus strange Unable to destroy activity exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

There are some questions here concerning AsyncTasks but I haven't been able to answer on my problem.

The main question is how to correctly inform the main code of the app that AsyncTask finished its work (how to send message)?

In my app I have the following structure:
- ViewPager (v4) plus many Fragments
- each Fragment links itself with AsyncTasks in onCreateView method and unlinks in onDestroy method (I mean refresh callback handler information)

In fragments I have the following structure:

```
MyFragment extends Fragment {

....

    /** callback handler for all Tasks */
    protected Handler handlerCallbackTask = new Handler() {
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

              switch (msg.what) {
                  case .....
```

And it seems to work although Eclipse generates HandlerLeak warning.

However I modified that slightly to have something like that:

```
MyFragment extends PMFragment {

....

protected Handler handlerCallbackTask;

public MyFragment() {
handlerCallbackTask = new HandlerClass();
 }


/** callback handler for all Tasks */
protected class HandlerClass extends Handler {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

          switch (msg.what) {
              case .....
```

Then suddently when changing screen orientation, the app started to generate the exceptions (what was suprising always during the second orientation change, never during the first one, upps), ex:

```
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {pitersoft.pitermemoflashcards/pitermemo.android.gui.activities.MainActivity}: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment MainActivityBrowser{41a700c8 #5 id=0x7f0a0010 android:switcher:2131361808:5} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3120)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3138)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:126)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment MainActivityBrowser{41a700c8 #5 id=0x7f0a0010 android:switcher:2131361808:5} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:1700)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1056)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1914)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:329)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:4629)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3107)
11-15 12:25:08.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26329):    ... 12 more
```

At first glance both Handlers seems to be the same. So I don't understand what is the difference.

Concluding:

1) Is there any difference between two handlers?

2) How AsyncTash should inform correctly the activity that task is finished.

3) Perhaps should I clean the messages queues when destroying Fragment? Should I and if yes how? (I'm wondering if this unable to destroy activity exception was related with the fact that some messages were in the queue)?

4) How to remove HandlerLeak warning? I don't want to make my Handler to be static as then I will not have access to my object.

5) At the end, how to force java to print the full exception stact (as you can see in the logcat it displays at the end "12 more" (and probably that could explain more the reasons of the exception).

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SuperNotCalledException
```

Your Exception is clearly answering you.

`super.onDestroy();` use this as first line in `onDestory()` method

as it needs finish the life cycle properly if `onDestroy()` or any other method is overridden

Answer (score 1):

Its not because of your handlers or anything..you have overriden the `onDestroy()` but not called its super method,,In your fragment class call `super.onDestoy()` in your `onDestroy(`) method..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. The reason was much more tricky that I've though.

super.onDestroy() method was in my onDestroy method body.

The problem was slightly different. I hasn't put super.onDestroy method as the first one but somewhere in the middle. Before there was some code with unregistering Handler. And I created my handler in constructor and set it to null in onDestroy method. I expected that Android when creates once again the Fragment will execute always constructor. But it seems not always. So I worked with null Handler which lead to problems.

Moving handlerCallbackTask = new HandlerClass(); to onCreateView method solved the problems.

There are still two things which is waiting for answer:

4) How to remove HandlerLeak warning? I don't want to make my Handler to be static as then I will not have access to my object.

5) At the end, how to force java to print the full exception stact (as you can see in the logcat it displays at the end "12 more" (and probably that could explain more the reasons of the exception).